# how to merge two images into one with asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an asp.net project. I am searching for a solution such that after a background image of a div is chosen. The user selects another image and coordinate. Then, this image will be merged on the background image with the defined coordinate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to combine two images,firstly you must upload them into server via ajax requests.
Read this article : [combining images](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/combining-images-with-csharp)

After you combine them,let the user download the new one.
Also if you're looking for an editor to do so,I suggest to place them on html5 canvas.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your post is quite general, but look in to System.Drawing and using an AJAX call to post both images (as well as the coordinates chosen) and then return the combined image which can then be displayed.

Without more specifics that's really all I can offer.